# Weirdly pixellated faces only in object mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, faces, topology

I've been trying to model a boot, but I've run into an issue with the topology. When in edit mode, the faces appear normal to me; [image: The faces in edit mode.]

But when I go into object mode, I find the faces to be weirdly pixellated;
[image: Model in object mode.]
Even with smooth shading, the faces appear all stretched even though they aren't stretched in edit mode.
I've tried removing doubles and recalculating normals several times, as well as adjusting vertices, but nothing seems to help.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: could you share your file?